# How to pass an argument in useCallback hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, react-hooks, gatsby

I'm trying to use the `useCallback` hook, to change the language using [`gatsby-intl`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-intl/) plugin, they have a method (`changeLocale()`) what can be used to change the default language of the site. I wanted to avoid passing props in JSX arrow's functions despite the solution is working so I'm trying to use the `useCallback` hook.

```
onClick={()=>switchLanguage(language.iso)}
```

Here's my component:

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { changeLocale } from 'gatsby-plugin-intl';
import { useLanguages } from '../../../hooks/useLanguages';

export const LanguageSwitcher = (callback, deps) => {
  const languages = useLanguages();

  const switchLanguage = useCallback(language => changeLocale(language),[]);

  return <ul>
    {languages.map((language, index) => <li key={index} onClick={switchLanguage(language.iso)}>{language.name}</li>)}
  </ul>;

};
```

The code above creates an infinite rendering, the code is entering on `switchLanguage` function without clicking it.

However, if I remove the argument, it works as expected but I don't know what language is the user clicking.

```
  const switchLanguage = useCallback(()=> console.log('item clicked'),[]);
```

I've also tried to use other hooks such as `useState` but it creates too many renders.

How can I pass an argument to the `useCallback`? If it is not possible, which will be the best workaround or approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onClick={switchLanguage(language.iso)}` **calls** `switchLanguage` and sets its return value as `onClick`, just like `onClick = switchLanguage(language.iso)` would outside JSX.

To bind the argument to it, you'd use a wrapper function:

```
onClick={() => switchLanguage(language.iso)}
```

...or `bind`, though it also creates a function:

```
onClick={switchLanguage.bind(null, language.iso)}
```

**But**: There's probably not much to be gained by using `useCallback` in your example. That being the case, you probably don't need `switchLanguage` at all:

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { changeLocale } from 'gatsby-plugin-intl';
import { useLanguages } from '../../../hooks/useLanguages';

export const LanguageSwitcher = (callback, deps) => {
  const languages = useLanguages();

  return <ul>
    {languages.map((language, index) => <li key={index} onClick={() => changeLocale(language.iso)}>{language.name}</li>)}
  </ul>;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply! Yes that was my first approach but I wanted to avoid to bind functions directly on JSX props. I guess my only option is to use something like this: `const switchLanguage = (language) => changeLocale(language);` and call switchLanguage `onClick` event

Comment: @FerranBuireu - Seems to be fairly standard practice these days. The thing to remember with `useCallback` is you're still recreating the function every time your component renders, it's just sometimes you're not using that new function. One of the fundamental assumptions of React hooks seems to be that creating functions is very, very fast. (I know modern engines reuse the code across instances of the functions, so it should be basically like creating an object.)

Comment: @FerranBuireu - *"I guess my only option is to use something like this: ` const switchLanguage = (language) => changeLocale(language);` and call switchLanguage onc"* I don't think theres really any reason for `switchLanguage` at that point, is there? Or does it do more than just call `changeLocale`?

Comment: Better to keep it simple and bind directly on JSX rather than create a useless function I guess. Thanks for the masterclass.

Comment: @FerranBuireu - LOL, as if. :-) Glad to help! Happy coding.